# Is it possible to modify RichText control from @pnp/spfx-controls-react to include Table support using React?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I have been working on creating a webpart for use in SharePoint Online where it uses the RichText control from [here](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/RichText/). So far its been working well and allowing for most formatting options, but its missing the capability to add Tables. Is there a possible way to add tables in there since its based on quill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gammaalpha,

The PnP control does not support adding table functionality. We've been looking at updating the library used by the RichText control so that we'd be able to support tables, but it is on a long list of features that we want to do.

Sorry!

Comment: Is there a possible time line for the update or is it a long way off like 1 year or more?

Comment: I'll try to do it as soon as I can, but it could be 6 months or so.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will try to find another solution in the mean time to see if it works with SPO or not. Since the existing default styling on the modern site pages tend to mess with the CSS of the toolbar when you deploy it. Which is super strange as it doesn't happen on the workbench.

Comment: @HugoBernier, was there update for supporting tables to RichText control? Is it available?

Comment: No, we were trying to change the richtext control for Microsoft's own (Rooster, if memory serves me right) but when we tried to do so, we ran into stability issues. It would be a great opportunity for someone in the community to revisit the issue...